# Can WebSocket pings occur in the middle of a message?

Tags: websocket, embedded

I am trying to simplify an embedded WebSocket implementation. Specifically, the requirement to buffer both the current message and some random interjected Ping seems quite useless (some say even impossible to use; see below) and particularly so in my application, which does not require long messages. This "requirement" consumes 1KB of embedded program FLASH, 140 bytes of RAM, some processing time, and considerable code review and testing effort, and seems to deliver no value. Is there a solid argument for why web browsers do not, and never will, interrupt message transmission with Pings?

RFC 6455, Section 5.4 Fragmentation says:

> Control frames (see Section 5.5) MAY be injected in the middle
> of a fragmented message.  Control frames themselves MUST NOT be
> fragmented.

However, [expert interpretation](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=13104#c6) seems to have established that something about the protocol design prevents the server from sending Pongs while it is sending a message:

> Imagine the WS client sends a WS Ping in the same moment the WS server
> is sending a very text frame to the client (let's say 10 MB). Due to
> the WS protocol design, the server cannot send a new frame (neither a
> Pong frame !!!) until the current frame is totally sent to the client.

I am not sure what it is about the protocol "design" that prevents a server from sending Pongs specifically in the middle of a fragmented message. Would the same "design" also prevent a client from sending Pings in the middle of a fragmented message?

Comment: RFC 6455 also notes these frames serve as keepalive or heartbeat messages. hence it has no purpose when a data transfer is already in progress. But nothing stops an endpoint from sending it.

Comment: @Liju Keepalive could be useful when a data transfer is in progress, if the data transfer is stalled for a long time.

Comment: Long stall or delay during data transfer is governed by underlying TCP with retransmission timeouts. Even if you send keep alive during a stall, it wont be sent immediately but queued, as per RFC793 3.8.

Comment: @liju. Sorry, I meant a bottleneck on the sender side, not a TCP stall. The point of WebSocket fragmentation is that the sender can send a fragment and then its disk slows down. It gets TCP acknowledgement (so no retransmission), but the remaining fragments aren't ready for a long time. That is when you would want to interject a ping. Having said that, it would be so much simpler if they just made the messages smaller instead of using fragments. I guess the inventors were trying to squeeze out every last bit of overhead. And failed to make the complexity optional.